# Looping over scheduling ETH transaction

Tags: solidity, transactions, scheduling

I have used Aion smart contracts to facilitate scheduling a ETH transaction. It works fine, but when it comes to making those transactions periodically (Scheduling multiple transactions), it throws an error.

What I am trying to say is that I have made one specific function that is responsible for taking two arguments ( nonce = number of payments, period = duration between payments ) beside my main scheduleTransaction() which is responsible for a single transaction scheduling, and I want to set up a group of automatic ETH transactions based on these characteristics. I'm going to attach my code. my loop seems fine, but it gives an error.

I would be thankful if anyone gives me a suggestion why whenever I try to execute scheduleMultipleTransaction(), it throws an error?

[image]

```
function scheduleTransaction(uint256 _fromNow) public {
    aion = AionContract(0x2fC197cD7897f41957F72e8E390d5a7cF2858CBF);
    uint256 callCost = 10e16 + 800000*100e9 + aion.serviceFee();
    aion.ScheduleCall.value(callCost)( block.timestamp + _fromNow, Reciever, 10e16, 800000, 100e9, hex"00", true);
}


function scheduleMultipleTransactions(uint _period, uint _nonce) public {
    for(uint i=0; i<=_period*(_nonce-1); i+_period) {
        scheduleTransaction(i);
    }
}

function () public payable {}
```

Lastly, I have to add that i had provided enough ETH to the contract prior to execution of these functions

Answer (score 1):

The code below is shown in the help for recurrent transactions:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

// interface Aion
contract Aion {
    uint256 public serviceFee;
    function ScheduleCall(uint256 blocknumber, address to, uint256 value, uint256 gaslimit, uint256 gasprice, bytes data, bool schedType) public payable returns (uint,address);

}

// Main contract
contract MyContract{
    Aion aion;

    constructor() public payable {
        scheduleMyfucntion();
    }

    function scheduleMyfucntion() public {
        aion = Aion(0xFcFB45679539667f7ed55FA59A15c8Cad73d9a4E);
        bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(keccak256('myfucntion()')));
        uint callCost = 200000*1e9 + aion.serviceFee();
        aion.ScheduleCall.value(callCost)( block.timestamp + 1 days, address(this), 0, 200000, 1e9, data, true);
    }

    function myfucntion() public {
        // do your task here and call again the function to schedule
        scheduleMyfucntion();
    }

    function () public payable {}

}
```

This code calls the function `MyFunction` every 24 hours. So the code that you want to execute every time should be included in `Myfunction`, for instance

```
function myfucntion() public {
    // do your task 
    (someAddress).transfer(amount);
     // then reschedule the transaction
     scheduleMyfucntion();
    }
```

That should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks to BRO JAIMEEEEEEEEEEEEEE the King